# Why can't I click the hyperlinks in my card slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to make a JavaScript slider which needs to work on both mobile and desktop. It should be possible to click on each and every card which should redirect me to another page.

At this moment I've got a working slider but I cannot click on any of the cards. This is caused by `pointer-events: none;` but the slider won't work without this line.

Does anyone know how to do this right or how I can approach this in other ways?

Thanks in advance,

```js
let slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
let innerSlider = document.querySelector(".slider-inner");

let pressed = false;
let startx;
let x;

//pc controls
slider.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startx = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  slider.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

slider.addEventListener("mouseevent", () => {
  slider.style.cursor = "grab";
});

slider.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  slider.style.cursor = "grab";
});

slider.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  pressed = false;
});

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;

  x = e.offsetX;
  let temp = x - startx;
  innerSlider.style.left = temp + "px";

  checkboundary();
});

function checkboundary() {
  let outer = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
  let inner = innerSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (parseInt(innerSlider.style.left) > 0) {
    innerSlider.style.left = "0px";
  } else if (inner.right < outer.right) {
    let temp = inner.width - outer.width;
    innerSlider.style.left = -temp + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.componentContainer {
  display: block;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.slider-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s ease-in;
  padding: 0 5px;

}

.slider-card {
  height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #dbdbdb;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-card a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="componentContainer">
    <h2>Onze promo's</h2>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="slider-card" onclick="window.location.href='/test'">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it is because you havent given the href address or the destination where you should go when the link is clicked

Comment: that wont be the problem sir, i edited them out for this post.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="componentContainer">
    <h2>Onze promo's</h2>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a slider-card>
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-card">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>test</span>
                    <span>lorem</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add A link first so you know it is clickable with the href.
Then you can just make a function on taping the class of the cards
like

```
$('.slider-card').on('click',()=>{...do smth...});
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried this with ```onclick="window.location.href='/test'"``` but that also doesn't work. I think the problem lies with the use of ```pointer-events: none;```

Comment: Of course! I hadn't notced that you had that on css. Just erase it from existence.
Look at this link to see how pointer events work : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this could be helpful or not, but I think you can detect user click by calculating slider left position on the mousedown and mouseup event, if in both events, slider's left position is the same, then you cand consider click has happened and do wathever you want when user clicks on one of the slides by JS. Something like this:

```
slider.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
 pressed = true;
 startx = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
 slider.style.cursor = "grabbing";
 sliderLeftPos = innerSlider.offsetLeft;
});

slider.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
 slider.style.cursor = "grab";
 const sliderCurrentLeftPos = innerSlider.offsetLeft;
 if (sliderCurrentLeftPos == sliderLeftPos) {
  alert('click');
 }
});
```

I've implemented my idea (no't detailed one) here: https://jsfiddle.net/saeed_shamloo/seyqp0gb/

I don't know it will help or not but I hope so.

Comment: seems to be doing what i need, but how do i get the right url from the clicked card?

Comment: Maybe you can do it by calculating the position of the point that has been clicked. see this fiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/saeed_shamloo/seyqp0gb/37/ by clicking on the slides you can see an alert with text related to the slide that has clicked.